# Cannot assign to read only property of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a duplicate array so I can edit the values and set it back also, here is what I got:

```
const handleInput: any = (index: any, property: any, value: any) => {
  const newCertificates = [...props.resume.certifications];
  newCertificates[index][property] = value;
  props.setResume({ ...props.resume, certifications: newCertificates })
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Certificates.tsx:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'certificationName' of object '#<Object>'
```

Comment: You're trying to modify your state directly, as the objects within `newCertificates` are still the same objects that they referred to in your original state.

Comment: @NickParsons can you share the solutions, how can I do that, by default isn't the first [...] cloning it?

Comment: I've added an answer to explain it in more detail

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to modify your state directly, as the objects within `newCertificates` are still the same objects that they referred to in your original state. Using `[...]` only creates a shallow copy of your array, so the objects within are not cloned (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72667033/5648954) for more details). On React, you shouldn't modify state directly as that can lead to issues with re-rendering, and that is what TS is trying to tell you with the error.

Rather than modifying these objects, use `.map()` on `props.resume.certifications` and then return a new object once you find the object that you need to modify and return a new object with the updated value:

```js
props.setResume(resume => ({
  ...resume,
  certifications: resume.certifications.map((obj, i) => 
    i === index ? {...obj, [property]: value} : obj
  )
}));
```

This way, you're only reading and never writing to your state value.